# A $2$-variable non-differentiable function whose partial derivatives exist

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If a $2$-variable function is not differentiable at some single point, but has finite partial derivatives for both variables at that point, can it also have a derivative in any direction, I mean is it valid to say that $dF/dl = \text{grad}F\cdot(l_1\cdot i + l_2\cdot j)$?

For example $f(x,y) = (x^3 - xy^2)/(x^2 + y^2)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$,

We need to determine the set of points $(x,y)$ from $R^2$ such that the function  has a derivative in every direction at any point.

Answer (score 0):

Your $f$ has directional derivatives everywhere on $\mathbb {R}^2.$ The only problem point is $(0,0).$ Check that $\partial f/\partial x (0,0) = 1, \partial f/\partial y (0,0)=0.$ Look along the lines $y = mx$ and see what happens in other directions. One interesting thing is that $f(x,x)\equiv 0.$ Thus the directional derivative in the direction $(1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2)$ is $0.$ However, $\nabla f (0,0) \cdot (1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2)  =1/\sqrt 2.$

Comment: Yes but the problem is in our book it says if the function is differentiable then it is valid to say that $gradf \mathbin{\cdot} e$ is a directional derivative.
Since it's not differentiable i try to do it by definition putting $X(0+ra,0+rb)$ and letting $r \to 0$ i get $$\frac{df(x)}{de} = \lim_{X\to A} \frac{f(X) - f(A)}{\rho(X,A)} = 0$$ so the directional derivative is $0$ in every direction, and therefore it exists even though the $gradf \cdot e$ is different (but I did say it could not be valid, since the function is not differentiable)

Comment: So what I'm really asking is If a function is not differentiable is there any other way to determine if it has directional derivatives in every point or do I have to do it by definition?

Comment: The directional derivative at $(0,0)$ is not equal to $0$ in every direction. Far from it; it is only equal to $0$ along $3$ different lines through the origin.